# Understanding chaining constructors with javascript's call()

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to understand chaining constructors with javascript's `call` function. I'm looking at an example from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

I've copied and pasted the example:

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0)
    throw RangeError('Cannot create product "' + name + '" with a negative price');
  return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);

function Toy(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'toy';
}
Toy.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);
```

What I'm confused about is that the `call` function for `Food` and `Toy` is called in their "constructor", but the object is not created until we called `Object.create(Product.prototype)` a few lines down... or so I thought.

Where exactly is the object being inherited created here? And what exactly is happening when we do `Product.call`? Is it creating an instance of `Product`? How does that relate to `Object.create(Product.prototype)`?

Comment: Maybe the following answer will help clarify some things: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 the answer given is good and correct, you can mark it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects are being declared and instantiated in these two lines that call the constructor function:

```
var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);
```

Before they are instantiated the function constructors `Food` and `Toy` are declared and their prototypes are set to an instance of `Product`.  This occurs in the following lines:

```
function Food(name, price) {/*omitted*/}
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);

function Toy(name, price) {/*omitted*/}
Toy.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

Regarding the calls to the parent constructor:

```
 Product.call(this, name, price);
```

This line will call the `Product` constructor assigning the `Food` or `Toy` instance to `this` in the call to the `Product` constructor while passing in the name and price arguments.  If your familiar with `Java` this is slightly similar to calling the `super()` constructor in a derived class.